# Putting a capacitor into a strong magnetic field, will this change the capacity?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, capacitance

I'm wondering, does a magnetic field change the number of electrons, placed and displaced on the two plates of a capacitor. To prove  or disprove this, I think the capacitor could be connected to an other capacitor outside the magnetic field and it has to be measured the current flowing between the capacitors during the increase and decrease of the magnetic field.

Edit: Was such an experiment carried out?

Comment: Will a changing magnetic field induce a current? Yes. Will that matter for the charge on capacitor? Depends on the geometry, doesn't it? Does anything follow for the capacitance? Look at how capacitance is defined.

Comment: @CuriousOne A capacitor, moved into a coil, with plates perpendicular to the coil, won't be affected by induction.

Comment: I don't know what plates "perpendicular to the coil" means. Honestly, the capacitor doesn't care that there is a coil, so why should we. It's all about the direction of the magnetic field. I am kind of failing to see how any of this is supposed to be related to the capacitance.

Comment: @CuriousOne Plates perpendicular to the coil's axis

Answer (score 3):

It is worth recalling that a charge that is at rest with respect to a static magnetic field incurs no force from that field. From that it follows that the steady-state capacitance should be identical to that of the same capacitor outside the field.

Or at least it would follow for a capacitor with vacuum between the plates. If there is a dielectric involved it we could at ask if the presence of the magnetic field has any effect on the dielectric constant of that material.

Comment: And indeed dielectrics do have some dependence on magnetic field, known as the _magnetodielectric effect_. This is typically weak but can be engineered to larger values. See, e.g., discussion in beginning of http://physics.aps.org/articles/v5/35 .

Answer (score 0):

> **does a magnetic field change the number of electrons, stored on a capacitor.**

No, because ...

1. The purpose of a capacitor is not to *store electrons* but to *store energy*. A "charged" capacitor contains the same number of electrons as an "uncharged" capacitor.
2. Electrons don't easily disappear or appear, they have to be moved somewhere. If you move the electrons around, you change the amount of stored energy, you don't change the capacitance.
3. The capacitance depends on factors like plate-area, separation-distance and  permittivity of separator. These are not normally affected by a magnetic field.

$$C = \epsilon \frac{A}{d}$$

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance): "Capacitance is the ability of a body to store an electrical charge. A material with a large capacitance holds more electric charge at a given voltage, than one with low capacitance. ". But you are right, the electrons that are stored on the one plate are missed on the second.  What I'm curious is, does a magnetic field change the number of electrons for a given voltage.

Comment: I edited my question.